# Remove watermark in spark streaming after deduplication

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, watermark

I'm trying to remove the watermark of my streaming job *after* deduplication. If I drop the column, I get an error:

```py
terminated with exception: None.get
```

If I don't remove it, the column shows up in the sink output which I don't want. How do I drop the column *after* deduplication has happened?